# How to compute a JSON field from other fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table containing the following fields

| id | sign1 | value1 | qty1 | sign2 | value2 | qty2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "positive" | "A" | 10 | "negative" | "B" | 5 |

How to create a SQL query that will generate a JSON object that will look like this?

```
{"A": 10, "B": -5}
```

Comment: 1) From here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html): `select json_build_object(value1, qty1, value2, qty2)`. Example: `select json_build_object('A', 10, 'B', 5);  {"A" : 10, "B" : 5}` 2) Is `-5` in the object a typo? If not then: `select json_build_object('A', 10, 'B', 5);  {"A" : 10, "B" : 5 * -1}`.

Comment: `"-5"` is not a typo. The sign is based on the signX column. Where can I add the condition to look for the signX column when building the object? The sign columns would contain strings. I just simplified it with only positive/negative for the example but basically based on the value of such column, the final sign of the number is determined.

Comment: hum maybe I can use `lateral` to compute the final value first using `CASE`? Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Normally (on stackoverflow.com) you should include what you tried to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty example:

```
create table json_object (id integer, sign1 varchar,  value1 varchar, qty1 integer, sign2 varchar,  value2 varchar,  qty2 integer);

insert into json_object values (1, 'positive', 'A', 10, 'negative', 'B', 5);

select json_build_object(value1, qty1 * (case when sign1 = 'positive' then 1 else -1 end), value2, qty2 * (case when sign2 = 'positive' then 1 else -1 end)) from json_object;

 json_build_object   
----------------------
 {"A" : 10, "B" : -5}
```

**UPDATE**
Add function to return 1 or -1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.positive_negative(sign character varying)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    output_val integer;
BEGIN
    if sign = 'positive' then
        output_val = 1;
    elsif sign = 'negative' then
        output_val = -1;
    end if;
RETURN output_val;
END;
$function$

select json_build_object(value1, qty1 * positive_negative(sign1), value2, qty2 * positive_negative(sign2)) from json_object;
  json_build_object   
----------------------
 {"A" : 10, "B" : -5}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Can I move the CASE into a function?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It's better than the lateral as the logic is not repeated.

Comment: See **UPDATE** that adds a function. Does not use `CASE` but achieves same thing.

Comment: Do you see an easy way to avoid including a value when there is no value? I am getting things like `"{"A" : 10, "B" : -5, "" : 0, "" : 0, "" : 0}"` because the other values are empty (optional)

Comment: That is going to come down to the selection criteria in your query e.g. `WHERE some_field = <some expression>`

Comment: but each value is hard coded in `json_build_object`: `json_build_object(value1, ..., value2, ...)` Basically I don't want to include value2 in building the object in the first place if it's empty. Maybe it needs a subquery?

Comment: I don't see how to add a criteria to only use the couples when each value is not empty. 
So looking into jsonb_object_agg and a subquery now. Any other idea?

Comment: You will need to update your question with more complete input data showing the case you are working with and the expected output.

Comment: I started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748411/dynamically-build-json-with-json-build-object) as the question is a bit different now.